# Uniquely identifying Azure VMs

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, uuid

We are looking for uniquely identifying Azure VMs (Linux), look like Azure VM has a UUID (since 9/18/2014).
This UUID is very generic, is there any way we can identify the UUID given is specific to Azure.
Please let me know if there any other mechanism too exist to identify a VM on Azure.

Regards,
Satyan.

Comment: where are you looking to do this? each resource in Azure is uniquely identified by its ID.

Comment: According to your description, it seems you find this link https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/accessing-and-using-azure-vm-unique-id/